# May one wear a jacket or coat over a tallit gadol during shacharit?

Tags: halacha, minhag, clothing, shacharis-morning-prayer, tallit-gadol

May one wear a jacket or coat over a tallit gadol during shacharit - assuming one wears a tallit gadol daily?

The reason I ask is because usually the tallit gadol is the outer most garment. I don't seem to recall any laws regarding tallitim or tzitzit that require them to be worn as the outer most garment.

Comment: No source, but i've seen people at shul do that.

Comment: @Scimonster, me too.

Comment: People regularly wear tzitzit on non-outermost-garments, no? I don't understand the question.

Comment: SA 8 says that the main purpose is that the tallit katan should be worn over the clothes. What's unclear, is what the rule is regarding the tallit gadol, esp. if you are wearing the tallit katan over your garments already. If you aren't, perhaps the gadol needs to be worn over the coat.